# Killing Activities using Back Button

Tags: android, back-button-control

I'd like to kill all activities when the user hits the back button and returns to my main activity A.  My App has the following 3 activities:

A -> Displays users selections before they hit search and creates activity B.
B -> Displays a list of urls's based on the users selection and creates activity C.

C -> Opens a Webview and displays the page selected by the user.

Currently, i don't call finish() after starting activity B so when the user hits the back button in activity C they can return to the list of url's and make another selection if they want.

I'd like to create a new activity A (without the users initial selections) and ensure the existing activities B and C are killed if the user hits the back button in activity B?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

O.

Answer (score 0):

You can return to activity A by overriding the back button handler in activity C and launching activity A with the flag [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) set, or alternatively (perhaps preferably in your case), you can just set [`noHistory`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) for your activity B.

You'll have to reset activity A manually in some way in this case though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  I'm assuming you meant overriding the back button in activity B? I tried the following from activity B but its not working?                                              `public void OnBackPressed(){
        Intent setIntent = new Intent(this,A.class);
        setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(setIntent); 
        super.onBackPressed();
}`